# Magento2: easiest way to delete a product attribute value without loading the product

Tags: magento2, massaction

I can update products efficiently without loading the whole product with

```
$this->productAction->updateAttributes([$productId], $attributesData, 0);
```

where `$attributesData` is an array, e.g. `['fabric' => 'cotton', 'pattern_repeat' => '50']`.

However I would like to delete attribute values too, without setting them to empty values, so actually deleted and not set to null.

There is no method in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action` for deleting an attribute value for a product, just setting or updating what is there.

How can I delete a product attribute option value without loading the whole product?